# Why do I get this JS error in console when switching out Revolution Slider in WordPress?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress, revolution-slider

Thank you for taking a look at my question.

I'm using the WordPress Divi theme and I have 2 code modules that with the help of Revolution Slider shortcode displays a carousel of screenshots for Android and iOs respectively:

[image: code modules]

What I want to do is when I click a button the display of the Android and iOs screenshots will toggle, e.g. I click the button the iOs carousel shows then if I click again it goes back to Android.

I've installed a plugin that helps me embed CSS and JS code, here's what I added to it:

*p.s. I do know that this code won't toggle, I'm just testing to see if I can get the display to switch:*

**CSS:**

```
 .removeCarousel{
    display:none;
   }
```

**JS:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">


    jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ){

      jQuery('.slider-link').click(function(e){
       e.preventDefault();  

        var text = jQuery(this).text();
        jQuery(this).text(text==="Android View" ? "iOs View" : "Android View");

        jQuery('.RL_iosView').addClass('removeCarousel');
        jQuery('.RL_AndroidView').RemoveClass('removeCarousel');

      });


    });
<script>
```

*The Android module starts off with the class removeCarousel.*

When I click the button I get these **errors in console**:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'left' of undefined
    at contWidthManager (jquery.themepunch.revolution.min.js?ver=5.3.1.5:8)
    at containerResized (jquery.themepunch.revolution.min.js?ver=5.3.1.5:8)
    at jquery.themepunch.revolution.min.js?ver=5.3.1.5:8
```

**AND**

```
invalid zIndex tween value: NaN
jquery.themepunch.tools.min.js?ver=5.3.1.5:104 invalid left tween value: NaN
jquery.themepunch.tools.min.js?ver=5.3.1.5:104 invalid zIndex tween value: NaN
jquery.themepunch.tools.min.js?ver=5.3.1.5:104 invalid left tween value: NaN
jquery.themepunch.tools.min.js?ver=5.3.1.5:104 invalid zIndex tween value: NaN
```

Those errors show in console and all I'm getting is the arrows of the carousel... any ideas on how to fix it or another way to implement what I'm trying to do??

**Thank you** immensely for any help you can provide!!

Comment: Even if you could, this is not something you **should** fix. Most likely, the version of the theme (and it's respective assets, including Revolution slider) is not compatible with your version of WordPress. Besides, Divi is a premium theme. You should address this directly to Elegant Themes. Most likely, they already have a patch for the bug. The only alternative (**strongly *not* recommended**) is to downgrade WordPress to a version compatible with your Divi version.